# Data labels are getting overlapped in core plot

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-plot, pie-chart

I am having pie chart in my application. Data labels are overlapping in coreplot whenever slice is very small.
Is there any way of adjusting frame of label or any other way of achieving this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, currently there's nothing you can do to improve the labelling. You could however rotate the pie chart to avoid the worst overlapping and show only pieces down to a minimum size. I have [opened a bug report](http://code.google.com/p/core-plot/issues/detail?id=382) for this problem a while ago already.